# Adding additional html to the end of the root level in a custom nav walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I have a custom nav walker, which essentially just add's new classes to the menu, however, my menu also contains some hard coded elements at the end (Contact button & Search Icon).

Where/How to I add this custom `<li>`'s in the nav walker to ensure that these get added in the root UL as the last items, only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code will helpful for you, add the items_wrap in wp_nav_menu to merge li's

```
<?php
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_id' => '', 'menu_class'=> '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s<li><a href="http://www.example.com/contact">Contact</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Search</a></li></ul>' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: A perfect. Why did I not spot that. Thanks.